# set log level with structlog

Tags: python, structlog

I am trying to setup structlog and set log level.  My code looks like this:

```
import structlog
import logging

filepath=open("out.log",'a')

logging.basicConfig(
  level=logging.INFO
)

structlog.configure(
    processors=[structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level],
    wrapper_class=structlog.BoundLogger,
    context_class=dict,
    logger_factory=structlog.PrintLoggerFactory(filepath),
)
logger = structlog.getLogger()
logger.info('test')
```

This fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/structlog/_base.py", line 189, in _proxy_to_logger
    args, kw = self._process_event(method_name, event, event_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/structlog/_base.py", line 149, in _process_event
    event_dict = proc(self._logger, method_name, event_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/structlog/stdlib.py", line 381, in filter_by_level
    if logger.isEnabledFor(_NAME_TO_LEVEL[name]):
AttributeError: 'PrintLogger' object has no attribute 'isEnabledFor'
```

Okay, sure.  I am not supposed to use PrintLogger with stdlib processors.  But I want to filter by log level (because that's how logging usually works, eh?)
So how do I do that?  I assume I need to use some other logger factory, but which one?
Of course structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory works, but it doesn't redirect to a file.

So I said: okay I will create my own filter:

```
def my_filter_by_level(logger, name, event_dict):
    if True:
        return event_dict
    else:
        raise DropEvent
```

...

```
processors=[my_filter_by_level],
```

And when I try to use the logger I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/structlog/_base.py", line 190, in _proxy_to_logger
    return getattr(self._logger, method_name)(*args, **kw)
TypeError: msg() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organization'
```

This is coming from

```
logger = logger.bind(**{"organization": "blah"})
```

but... why?  What is wrong with my processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason my filter didn't work is this:
https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/processors.html#adapting

Last filter in chain is special and can't just return a dictionary.

And the following filter did the trick:

```
def my_filter_by_level(logger, name, event_dict):
    this_level = structlog.stdlib._NAME_TO_LEVEL[name]
    set_level = structlog.stdlib._NAME_TO_LEVEL[loglevel]
    if this_level >= set_level:
        return event_dict
    else:
        raise structlog.DropEvent
```

Answer (score 18):

Here's another way to set the default log level.  It outputs all levels above 'INFO'.

```py
import logging
import structlog

structlog.configure(
    wrapper_class=structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(logging.INFO),
)

log = structlog.get_logger()
```